# Multiple domains on different servers with 1 nat rule

Tags: iis, apache-2.4

I am pretty new to this and cant get it figured out.
I have 2 domains. 1 domain should go to 1 web-server, the other to a 2nd. 1 is on IIS and the other on Apache.
on my router i can only make 1 NAT rule for http/https.

so all traffic goes to 1 web-server. in this case the Apache one. 
Is it possible to forward all the HTTP/HTTPS requests for that other domain from the Apache machine to the IIS machine? Without losing the URL of course.

domain1.com -> Apache
domain2.com -> IIS
Both behind 1 router with only 1 NAT rule

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

If the websites on each of the servers are on different ports you can with 2 Nat rules for the corresponding ports, otherwise you'll need to introduce a reverse proxy that can look at the url they're coming in on and route it to the correct backend server. Nginx works well for this, but will be a bit more technical as you'll point your nat rule to NginX, then tell NgninX how to route to the two servers.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. You need to configure the Apache server as a proxy for the other server.

This is the basic configuration you need, extend as necessary and fill in the correct internal address of your IIS server.

```
<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName domain2.com
  ProxyPass "/" "http://iis-server/"
  ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```